# How to guarantee lock acquisition

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some struct `Foo` that is continuously updated by a thread. Let's call this "Thread B"

```
while (true) {
  // Do some work for about 300 ms
  {
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(some_mutex);
    // update Foo
  }
}
```

Then on the main thread (call it Thread A) I have a function that I can call at any time (given user input) to get the latest information in `Foo` as soon as some conditions are met.

```
while (true) {
  std::getchar()  // Wait for a user to request this service
  {
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(some_mutex);
    if (/* check some things in Foo */) {
      // Read the data in Foo and do some relatively quick processing
      return some_data;
    }
  }
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
}
```

I didn't originally have that `sleep_for` in there but I realised that the program would sometimes hang indefinitely, and I supposed it was because Thread A just kept reacquiring the lock without giving Thread B a chance to update `Foo`. The sleep did fix the problem but now I find myself worrying about whether it's a guaranteed fix. Is it? If so, what's the minimum amount of sleep I need so that Thread A doesn't hog the lock? Is there a more explicit way of solving this problem?

Comment: Use a `condition_variable` instead.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: Sleeping in multithreaded code is not the proper way to ensure safety or liveness. Trying to figure out the "minimal sleep" that makes your code to apparently work, today, on your PC is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Why does thread A need to run more often than the data are updated? If thread A does _not_ actually _need_ to run more often, then why can't you do all of the work in a single thread?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'm not sure that  would work. Thread B in my application is actually a 3d scanner and Foo contains the 3d point cloud and other metadata. I need the scanner to just acquire over and over without being interrupted. Thread A is a user input "I want the next scan that has metadata x, y, z". I don't want Thread B to stop just because it found what the user wanted. It should keep running indefinitely.